# How to achieve base64 url safe encoding in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, encryption, base64, web-push

I am currently trying to get Web Push Notifications (GCM/FCM) working in VB.NET.
I can push a tickle(push with no payload) with no problem, but I need to send a payload and therefore, I am required to use the encryption methods outlined in the [Google Web Push Encryption Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption). This is a little out of my depth.

I found a C# sample online [Encrypting Payload for Web Push](http://seehashrun.blogspot.co.uk/2016/09/encrypting-data-for-web-browser-push.html)
which I am attempting to port to VB.NET but at the moment I'm struggling to achieve URL safe Encoding/Decoding in VB.NET

The C# equivalent to what I need are : WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode and WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode

But I cannot find any information as to how I can acheive this in VB, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it's part of [Microsoft.AspNetCore](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/WebUtilities/WebEncoders/). You can just get it through nugget.

Comment: you found a sample for c# -> all the used libraries are .net libraries -> VB.net can use the same libs ... so ... where exactly is the problem? converting c# code to vb.net?

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense, however,  I'm unable to install ASPNetCore because I'm using .NETFramework v4.5 (which, unfortunatley I'm unable to change). 

So I guess what I'm actually asking is, is there any other way to achieve the same result by :

a) using a different namespace (compatible with .NET 4.5)
or
b) writing my own function

Comment: I have tried to install [Micosoft.AspNet.WebUtilities](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities/) too but this also fails, it looks like the WebEncoders only came into play in .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Isn't this function the equivalent for vb.net to the ones you've quotes in #c?
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yours to encode"))

Comment: No to the above because it doesn't support URL safe encoding